# Is always running Visual Studio as Administrator really a Microsoft Best Practice?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have been told be a support team that my issue when running VS as non-admin is not really a bug, and I should always run VS as admin, as this is an MS Best Practice.  I cannot find any such statement from MS.  Can anyone verify or dispute this?

Please note that I am questioning the objectivity of their statemement in an objective question.  I am not asking what practice is best, but whether MS has ever called this one of their Best Practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS has recommended this for VS2005. Not 2008/2010.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa972193

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165100.aspx